# Testing for destroyed users in devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, ruby-on-rails-4, testing, devise

I am currently having trouble testing for destroying users generated with devise.

```
require 'test_helper'
class UserTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  # test "the truth" do
  #   assert true
  # end
  def setup
    @user = User.new(email: "user@example.com")
  end

  test "Should delete User"do
    @user.save
    assert_difference 'User.count', -1 do
     @user.destroy
    end
  end

end
```

Currently the tests
fail and show that the difference was 0. I was wondering how I could test this (even though I know user.destroy works when I run it in a rails console).

All the best
D

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think, there is problem with saving the user `@user.save`. This is due the validation error. Default `Devise`s `User` has a `password` as a mandatory field.

Try changing:

```
def setup
  @user = User.new(email: "user@example.com")
end
```

to:

```
def setup
  @user = User.new(email: "user@example.com",
                   password: "SuperS3cret")
end
```

The `@user` should be properly saved, and it make `@user.destroy` to work, and `assert_difference` to pass.

Good luck!